# Is there a more accurate way to do booleans with geonodes?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, geometry-nodes, geometry

I have a technique to do better fluid / glass interaction in blender... shown below:

[image]

This is all fine and good, but its somewhat of a pain in the ass to setup, since it makes use of booleans and flipping normals and other things...

This shouldnt be all that complex to reproduce in geonodes. My issue though, is that the booleans used in geonodes are shit. I dont mean that as a mock... Theyre literally terrible.

Any basic operation causes a mess of vertices and faces...

[image]

With normal booleans, usually swapping to fast fixes these kinds of issues... From what I can tell, it appears that geonodes is using the "exact" booleans from the modifier... Theyre usually terrible in my experience..

Is there any way that I can use the "fast" booleans in geonodes, or is there some better alternative? I cant even do basic intersections without completely breaking the mesh.

This technique for fluid interaction has to be perfectly precise... and the "exact" booleans are, funnily enough, never exact... they always break.

Comment: In my experience the "exact" method in booleans works really well with perfectly manifold meshes. Did you make sure your meshes are manifold ?

Comment: @Gorgious yes, theyre manifold